# How to retrieve a value of a variable which is itself a value of another variable in ant script?

Tags: apache, variables, ant

In ant script, I receive value **def** when called as ${abc} but not the value **xyz** when called as ${${abc}}.

The property file which script calls has values listed as below:

`abc = def
def = xyz`

Any idea how could a value of variable be used as a variable itself in ant script?

Answer (score 1):

See Ant FAQ "[Double expanding the property](https://ant.apache.org/faq.html#propertyvalue-as-name-for-property)"